# Android app - basic icon button without text

Tags: android, android-studio, android-button

How do I make a basic icon button without text or background? For example, just a simple vector image from @drawables that, when clicked, shows that circular response thing around it. I don't want the icon to have any background color to it. Just an icon that can be clicked, that's literally it.

I can only figure out how to do it by creating a `menu` and setting the icon as an `item` with `app:showAsAction="always"`. It seems like there must be a better way to do this.

Edit: Here's an example of what I want to achieve. It's very basic. Just a clickable icon with responsive feedback when touched. https://material-ui.com/components/buttons/#icon-buttons

It's exactly the same as creating the following. I just thought there was likely an easier way to do this without having to create and load a menu just for one single icon:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_contacts"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_contacts_24"
        android:title="@string/action_contacts"
        app:iconTint="@android:color/white"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

Comment: so what is your exact question ?

Comment: I just want to make this in Android. The question is "how?". I thought that was pretty obvious... https://material-ui.com/components/buttons/#icon-buttons

Comment: @GCM `shows that circular response thing around it` this is far from obvious...did you mean a "ripple" animation when the button is pressed?

Comment: Yes. I've edited my question to make it clearer. Here is an example of exactly what I want to achieve - https://material-ui.com/components/buttons/#icon-buttons

Comment: @GCM check this [Icon button](https://material.io/develop/android/components/material-button/)

Comment: I've tried that example. It's different to https://material-ui.com/components/buttons/#icon-buttons. That example has a square background. I'm trying to achieve the same thing as what happens by default when you create a `menu` `item` with an icon and no text.

Comment: @GCM You're using the word "button" and "menu" indistinctively. Is it a menu item or a button? They're not the same thing

Comment: It's a button. I want the styling to be the same as if it were a menu item icon. i.e. icon only, no background image, appropriate padding, when clicked it has a circular ripple effect. If you check the link I provided it shows an example of EXACTLY what I want to achieve.

Comment: https://material-ui.com/components/buttons/#icon-buttons - look at the trash can icon. That's exactly what I want. It's just an icon that when touched, has a ripple effect. This is the exact same thing that occurs when you create a menu item that is an icon only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> First create a `vector drawable` and then add to the `ImageView` like
>   this:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_delete" />
```

Comment: This is getting closer. I had to add 
                `android:clickable="true"` and 
                `android:focusable="true"`, however the ripple effect is square, not circular.

Comment: Actually I didn't notice that you changed to Borderless. That actually got it working! Thanks heaps, marking this as correct. I knew there was an easy way to do this...

Comment: Oh and I also had to add 4dp padding to it as well.

Comment: Yes, borderless made it so that it's a circular ripple instead of square.

Comment: @GCM I wonder what was the difference in the answer I provided from the beginning...?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `MaterialButton`, `ImageButton` and even an `ImageView` for this. Here's an example of how you'd do it with an `ImageView`...

```
        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:src="@drawable/your_icon" />
```

All you need to do is set the `selectableItemBackground`, this will use your theme's primary color (or maybe the secondary color, I can't remember).

Now if you want a different color for ripple effect, for example a grey ripple, then you can create the drawable yourself...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:color="#dddddd">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <color android:color="#dddddd" />
    </item>
</ripple>
```

and set the view background below..

```
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

it'll work with any view provided the view is clickable

Comment: This creates a background color behind the icon. Also, clicking the button doesn't provide any ripple effects.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `ImageView` if you like, but if you want to generate the complete image (including frame/borders) yourself you don't have to go that far. You could practically use plain `View` (except that you'd have to supply `android:layout_width/height` explicitly). Just use `Button` and have the `android:background` specify a selector which will select between images.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/clear1" android:state_pressed="true"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/clear0"/>
</selector>
```